# calculate total of rows all in the same column in sql database

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a sql table called expenses with an int column called cost. In my application this data is displayed on a grid which is refreshing every time I insert a new row with a linq2sql insert. What I would like to do is have an integer variable in my application that is the sum of all the fields in the cost column every time I insert a row.

Is there a simple way to sum these fields with linq2sql every time I do an insert. Please try to avoid lambda as I haven't gotten to learning that yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you use query syntax instead of lambdas, here you are:

```
var totalCost = (from expensesRow in dataContext.Expenses
             select expensesRow.cost)
             .Sum();
```

Which in fact is the same as:

```
var totalCost = dataContext.Expenses
                  .Sum(x => x.cost);
```

Here `dataContext` is an instance of your Linq2Sql `DataContext` class.

Comment: @adam355 You're wellcome. But, please, do consider learning lambdas. :)

Answer (score 1):

You get to learn lambdas today. http://www.theabsentmindedcoder.com/2010/06/linq-sum.html has *exactly* what you want, and uses a very simple lambda to get there. You could get away without the lambda by making your select gather up only the one column of integers you're trying to sum, but why do extra work to not learn things?

Answer (score 0):

Say I had a table called users with the following structure:

```
[Table users] -  id | username | points_awarded
```

Then, I can find the total number of points I awarded every user by running the query:

```
SELECT SUM(points_awarded) as total_points FROM users
```

You can also count how many users have points greater than our equal to N. For example, says N = 500, then I can run:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as num_users_with_points FROM users WHERE points_award >= 500
```

Check out:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/func-op-summary-ref.html
```

for more information.

Comment: Isnt that a straight sql query? I am using linq2sql